# Run grunt watch from the startup windows 10

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a way to open the command prompt and run grunt watch from my project directory each time my PC starts?  Just trying to automate the automation, have spent a good half hour googling with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one module which installs a node script as a windows service, it's called node-windows (npm, github, documentation). I've used before and worked like a charm.

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;    
// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
name:'Hello World',
description: 'The nodejs.org example web server.',
script: 'C:\\path\\to\\helloworld.js'
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

Installing it:

```
npm install -g qckwinsvc
```

Installing your service:

```
> qckwinsvc
prompt: Service name: [name for your service]
prompt: Service description: [description for it]
prompt: Node script path: [path of your node script]
Service installed
```

Uninstalling your service:

```
> qckwinsvc --uninstall
prompt: Service name: [name of your service]
prompt: Node script path: [path of your node script]
Service stopped
Service uninstalled
```